# Use putty to connect to XP host under VMWare

Tags: windows-7, vmware, putty

I have windows 7 64 as host and windows xp & Red hat linux as guest via vmware. They are working well. now i want to connect to winxp and redhat linux from host via putty.

But when I tried to connect to Windows XP the result is `connection refused`. I can't communicate via putty either by entering the guest (Windows xp) IP address or name. I have installed putty in host OS (Windows 7 x64).

Is it neccessary to switch on vmware with guest os while interacting through putty?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact with Windows XP using putty, then it needs to be running a service that putty can communicate with.

Ideally, this would be an SSH server, so installing something like http://www.freesshd.com/ would allow you to log into Windows XP using ssh through putty.

You are seeing a connection refused because XP does not understand ssh natively and so is not listening on port 22.  Redhat on the other hand installs an ssh server by default.